# case_when function from R to Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

How I can implement the case_when function of R in a python code?

Here is the case_when function of R:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when

as a minimum working example suppose we have the following dataframe (python code follows):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73], 
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
df
```

Suppose than we want to create an new column called 'elderly' that looks at the 'age' column and does the following:

```
if age < 10 then baby
 if age >= 10 and age < 20 then kid 
if age >=20 and age < 30 then young 
if age >= 30 and age < 50 then mature 
if age >= 50 then grandpa
```

Can someone help on this ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You want to use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```py
conditions = [
    (df["age"].lt(10)),
    (df["age"].ge(10) & df["age"].lt(20)),
    (df["age"].ge(20) & df["age"].lt(30)),
    (df["age"].ge(30) & df["age"].lt(50)),
    (df["age"].ge(50)),
]
choices = ["baby", "kid", "young", "mature", "grandpa"]

df["elderly"] = np.select(conditions, choices)

# Results in:
#      name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore  elderly
#  0  Jason   42             4             25   mature
#  1  Molly   52            24             94  grandpa
#  2   Tina   36            31             57   mature
#  3   Jake   24             2             62    young
#  4    Amy   73             3             70  grandpa
```

The `conditions` and `choices` lists must be the same length.
There is also a `default` parameter that is used when all `conditions` evaluate to `False`.

Comment: thank you, and what if in the conditions want to have strings as opposed to numerical values. For example, if age == "fourty" then 'marure'. `' How your code could be modified?

Comment: Then I’d use `df[“age”].eq(“fourty”)` as this allows us to continue using the bitwise `&`.

Comment: How the code can be modified so as to put all other cases in one condition? For example, the 'greater than 50' condition is redundant essentially. So, maybe is better practice to have the last condition: 'anything else then grandpa'.

Comment: There is a `default` parameter on `np.select`, this is used when all conditions evaluate to `False`: `np.select(conditions, choices, default='Grandpa')`. You could then remove the last elements from both the `conditions` and `choices` lists.

Answer (score 12):

`np.select` is great because it's a *general* way to assign values to elements in choicelist depending on conditions.

However, for the particular problem OP tries to solve, there is a succinct way to achieve the same with the pandas' `cut` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

```py
bin_cond = [-np.inf, 10, 20, 30, 50, np.inf]            # think of them as bin edges
bin_lab = ["baby", "kid", "young", "mature", "grandpa"] # the length needs to be len(bin_cond) - 1
df["elderly2"] = pd.cut(df["age"], bins=bin_cond, labels=bin_lab)

#     name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore  elderly elderly2
# 0  Jason   42             4             25   mature   mature
# 1  Molly   52            24             94  grandpa  grandpa
# 2   Tina   36            31             57   mature   mature
# 3   Jake   24             2             62    young    young
# 4    Amy   73             3             70  grandpa  grandpa
```

Answer (score 3):

[pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) has a [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.case_when.html#janitor.case_when) implementation in `dev` that could be helpful in this case, the implementation idea is inspired by [if_else](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dt/ifelse.html) in `pydatatable` and [fcase](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/fcase) in R's `data.table`; under the hood, it uses [pd.Series.mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

df.case_when(
df.age.lt(10), 'baby', # 1st condition, result
df.age.between(10, 20, 'left'), 'kid', # 2nd condition, result
df.age.between(20, 30, 'left'), 'young', # 3rd condition, result
 df.age.between(30, 50, 'left'), 'mature', # 4th condition, result
'grandpa',  # default if none of the conditions match
 column_name = 'elderly') # column name to assign to
 
    name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore  elderly
0  Jason   42             4             25   mature
1  Molly   52            24             94  grandpa
2   Tina   36            31             57   mature
3   Jake   24             2             62    young
4    Amy   73             3             70  grandpa
```

[Alby's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65590670/7175713) solution is more efficient for this use case than an if/else construct.

Answer (score 1):

Just for Future reference, Nowadays you could use pandas cut or map with moderate to good speeed. If you need something faster It might not suit your needs, but is good enough for daily use and batches.

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

If you wanna choose map or apply mount your ranges and return something if in range

```
def calc_grade(age):
        if 50 < age < 200:
            return 'Grandpa'
        elif 30 <= age <=50:
            return 'Mature'
        elif 20 <= age < 30:
            return 'Young'
        elif 10 <= age < 20:
            return 'Kid'
        elif age < 10:
            return 'Baby'

%timeit df['elderly'] = df['age'].map(calc_grade)
```

|  | name | age | preTestScore | postTestScore | elderly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jason | 42 | 4 | 25 | Mature |
| 1 | Molly | 52 | 24 | 94 | Grandpa |
| 2 | Tina | 36 | 31 | 57 | Mature |
| 3 | Jake | 24 | 2 | 62 | Young |
| 4 | Amy | 73 | 3 | 70 | Grandpa |

393 µs ± 8.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

---

If you wanna choose cut there should be many options.
One approach - We includes to left, exclude to the right . To each bin, one label.

```
bins = [0, 10, 20, 30, 50, 200] #200 year Vampires are people I guess...you could change to a date you belieave plausible.
labels = ['Baby','Kid','Young', 'Mature','Grandpa']

%timeit df['elderly'] = pd.cut(x=df.age, bins=bins, labels=labels , include_lowest=True, right=False, ordered=False)
```

|  | name | age | preTestScore | postTestScore | elderly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jason | 42 | 4 | 25 | Mature |
| 1 | Molly | 52 | 24 | 94 | Grandpa |
| 2 | Tina | 36 | 31 | 57 | Mature |
| 3 | Jake | 24 | 2 | 62 | Young |
| 4 | Amy | 73 | 3 | 70 | Grandpa |

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has just released a `case_when` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.case_when.html).

```py
caselist=[(df.age.lt(10), 'baby'), 
          (df.age.ge(10) & df.age.lt(20), 'kid'), 
          (df.age.ge(20) & df.age.lt(30), 'young'), 
          (df.age.ge(30) & df.age.lt(50), 'mature'), 
          (df.age.ge(50), 'grandpa')]

df.assign(elderly = df.age.case_when(caselist=caselist))
    name  age  preTestScore  postTestScore  elderly
0  Jason   42             4             25   mature
1  Molly   52            24             94  grandpa
2   Tina   36            31             57   mature
3   Jake   24             2             62    young
4    Amy   73             3             70  grandpa
```

Answer (score 0):

Steady of numpy you can create a function and use map or apply with lambda:

```
def elderly_function(age):
 if age < 10:
  return 'baby'
 if age < 20:
  return 'kid'
 if age < 30
  return 'young'
 if age < 50:
  return 'mature'
 if age >= 50:
  return 'grandpa'

df["elderly"] = df["age"].map(lambda x: elderly_function(x))
# Works with apply as well:
df["elderly"] = df["age"].apply(lambda x: elderly_function(x))
```

The solution with numpy is probably fast and might be preferable if your df is considerably large.